# Last token in batch delimited by minus

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have a string "xx-yy-zz"

I need to get the part after the last minus character.

Usually, I do it that way

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%i IN ("xx-yy-zz") DO SET USER_COUNTRY=%%k
echo Country: %USER_COUNTRY%
```

But now I don't have the string with a fixed length (there could be 2/3/4 delimiters)

How can I specify that I want the last one? So I have the code that would work for "xx-yy-zz" and also for "xx-yy-zz-aa"

Could someone help with this, please?

Comment: `tokens=1-4` would assign the last part to `%%l` if `aa` is present; you could do an `if` query to check if it is empty; so like this: `for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-" %%i in ("xx-yy-zz-aa") do (set "USER_COUNTRY=%%l" & if not defined USER_COUNTRY set "USER_COUNTRY=%%k" & if not defined USER_COUNTRY set "USER_COUNTRY=%%j")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use a plain `for` (without `/f`):

```
set string=xxx-yyy-zzz
for %%a in (%string:-= %) do set last=%%a
echo %last%
```

`(%string:-= %` replaces every `-` with a space, so the `for` can split the string into tokens and assign every one of them to (the same) variable, resulting in the variable holding the last token.

Comment: It also fails if the string already contains equal, space, comma, or semicolon (or tab or /0xFF, but those are highly unlikely)

Comment: Considering the expected result is named `User_Country` and two-letter-tokens, none of those characters are likely.

Comment: Using `"%string:-=" "%"` and `%%~a` would avoid problems related to the token separators @dbenham mentioned...

Answer (score 3):

The option string `tokens=1-4` would let the `for /F` loop assign the last string portion `aa` to variable reference `%%l` if it is present; `%%l` would be empty otherwise. So you could do an `if` query to check for emptyness and use `%%k` instead in case, and so on, like this:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-" %%i in ("xx-yy-zz-aa") do (
    set "USER_COUNTRY=%%l"
    if not defined USER_COUNTRY set "USER_COUNTRY=%%k"
    if not defined USER_COUNTRY set "USER_COUNTRY=%%j"
)
echo/%USER_COUNTRY%
```

---

An alternative method would be this:

```cmd
set "STRING=xx-yy-zz-aa"
set "DUMMY=%STRING:-=" & set "USER_COUNTRY=%"
echo/%USER_COUNTRY%
```

This approach might fail if the input string contains `"` characters.

Comment: Was about to post the very same self expanding code variant when I realized I was too late. BTW no delayed expansion needed here.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to convert the string, replacing dashes with backslashes so it *"seems"* a path that can be handled with a `for` command

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "string=xxx-yyy-zzz"
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ("::%string:-=\%") do set "last=%%~nxa"

    echo %last%
```

Comment: This is great, +1! obviously it might fail in case the input string contains `\ `or `/`...

Comment: @aschipfl, yes, it is necessary to deal with the problem if the last element in the string (previous values do not interfere) could contain a slash or backslash

Comment: It also has a problem if the string ends with dot or space.

Answer (score 2):

An additional example:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set/P "InString=Enter your delimited string: "
Echo=
If "%InString%"=="" GoTo :EOF
Set/P "Delimiter=Enter the delimiter: "
Echo=
If "%Delimiter%"=="" GoTo :EOF
Set "Delimiter=%Delimiter:~,1%"
:Loop
If Defined InString (
    For /F "EOL=%Delimiter% Tokens=1* Delims=%Delimiter%" %%A In ("%InString%"
    ) Do (Set "LastToken=%%A" & Set "InString=%%B") & GoTo Loop
) Else Set LastToken
Timeout -1
Exit/B
```

*This version will still have issues with some characters*